# How to configure Apache Superset?

Tags: configuration, apache-superset

The below details are provided in the official documentation for the configuration of Apache superset. But I couldn't understand the process clearly. Can anyone explain in detail how to configure the Apache Superset. Also, I have installed Apache Superset in my Windows PC using Ubuntu Terminal. I couldn't find the Superset repository in my PC to check the config.py file. After installing Apache Superset by using Ubuntu terminal, can anyone explain how to configure it and what are the steps to follow to do the configuration process?

Link: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset

> To configure your application, you need to create a file
> superset_config.py. Add this file to your
>
> PYTHONPATH or create an environment variable SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH
> specifying the full path of the superset_config.py.
>
> For example, if deploying on Superset directly on a Linux-based system
> where your superset_config.py is under /app directory, you can run:
>
> `export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset_config.py`
>
> If you are using your own custom Dockerfile with official Superset
> image as base image, then you can add your overrides as shown below:
>
> ```
> COPY --chown=superset superset_config.py /app/ ENV
> SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH /app/superset_config.py
> ```
>
> Docker compose deployments handle application configuration
> differently. See
> https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker#readme for
> details.
>
> The following is an example of just a few of the parameters you can
> set in your superset_config.py file.

I have tried all the possibilities and searched in all the community forums, but I couldn't find any solution for the configuration of Apache superset clearly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want you to configure Apache Superset, you need to override the configuration with a new file named "superset_config.py" and you need to place underneath the installation folder but it depends on your installation or you can point to it with
`export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/superset_config.py` for Linux
or in windows with `set SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset_config.py`
and after that you can configure what ever you want in superset.